# get error in definition

Tags: c

Hi
first I like to thank you all for your help
We have to use complier code wrote in book
but I have error in defining one of the functions lexan
can you help me solve it I mark it bold

```
/* global.h */

#include <stdio.h>  /* include declarations for i/o routines */
#include <ctype.h>  /* ... and for character test routines */
#include <stdlib.h> /* ... and for some standard routines, such as exit */
#include <string.h> /* ... and for string routines */

#define BSIZE  128  /* buffer size */
#define NONE   -1
#define EOS    '\0'

#define NUM    256
#define DIV    257
#define MOD    258
#define ID     259
#define DONE   260

extern int tokenval = NONE;   /*  value of token attribute */  
extern int lineno = 1;

struct entry {  /*  form of symbol table entry  */
  char *lexptr; 
  int  token;    
};

extern struct entry symtable[];  /* symbol table  */

extern void init();  /*  loads keywords into symtable  */
extern void error(char* m);  /*  generates all error messages  */
/*BOLD*/ extern int lexan();  /*  lexical analyzer  */**
extern void parse();  /*  parses and translates expression list  */
extern int insert(char *s, int tok);  /*  returns position of entry for s */
extern int lookup(char *s);  /*  returns position of entry for s */
extern void emit (int t, int tval);  /*  generates output  */
/* init.c */

struct entry keywords[] = {
  { "div", DIV },
  { "mod", MOD, },
  { 0,     0 }
};

void init()  /*  loads keywords into symtable  */
{
  struct entry *p;
  for (p = keywords; p->token; p++)
    insert(p->lexptr, p->token);
}
/* symbol.c */


#define STRMAX 999  /*  size of lexemes array  */
#define SYMMAX 100  /*  size of symbol table */

char lexemes[STRMAX];
int  lastchar = - 1;  /*  last used position in lexemes   */
struct entry symtable[SYMMAX];
int lastentry = 0;    /*  last used position in symtable  */

int lookup(char *s)         /*  returns position of entry for s */
{
  int p;
  for (p = lastentry; p > 0; p = p - 1)
    if (strcmp(symtable[p].lexptr, s) == 0)
      return p;
  return 0;
}

int insert(char *s, int tok)    /*  returns position of entry for s */
{
  int len;
  len = strlen(s);  /*  strlen computes length of s     */
  if (lastentry + 1 >= SYMMAX)
    error ("symbol table full");
  if (lastchar + len + 1 >= STRMAX)
    error ("lexemes array full");
  lastentry = lastentry + 1;
  symtable[lastentry].token = tok;
  symtable[lastentry].lexptr = &lexemes[lastchar + 1];
  lastchar = lastchar + len + 1;
  strcpy(symtable[lastentry].lexptr, s);
  return lastentry;
}
/* lexer.c */


char lexbuf[BSIZE];


int lexan ()  /*  lexical analyzer  */
{

  int t;
  while(1) {
    t = getchar ();
    if (t == ' ' || t == '\t')
      ;  /*  strip out white space  */
    else if (t == '\n')
      lineno = lineno + 1;
    else if (isdigit (t)) {  /*  t is a digit  */
      ungetc(t, stdin);
      scanf("%d", &tokenval);
      return NUM;
    }
    else if (isalpha(t)) {  /*  t is a letter */
      int p, b = 0;
      while (isalnum(t)) {  /* t is alphanumeric  */
        lexbuf [b] = t; 
        t = getchar ();
        b = b + 1;
        if (b >= BSIZE)
          error("compiler error");
      }
      lexbuf[b] = EOS;
      if (t != EOF)
        ungetc(t, stdin);
      p = lookup (lexbuf);
      if (p == 0)
        p = insert (lexbuf, ID);
      tokenval = p;
      return symtable[p].token;
    }
    else if (t == EOF)
      return DONE;
    else {
      tokenval = NONE;
      return t;
    }
  }
}

/* emitter.c */
void emit (int t, int tval)  /*  generates output  */
{
  switch(t) {
  case '+' : case '-' : case '*' : case '/':
    printf("%c\n", t); break;
  case DIV:
    printf("DIV\n"); break; 
  case MOD:
    printf("MOD\n"); break;
  case NUM:
    printf("%d\n", tval); break;
  case ID:
    printf("%s\n", symtable[tval].lexptr); break; 
  default:     
    printf("token %d, tokenval %d\n", t, tval);
  }
}
/* parser.c -- without the optimizations */

int lookahead;

void match(int);
void start(), list(), expr(), moreterms(), term(), morefactors(), factor();

void parse()  /*  parses and translates expression list  */
{
  lookahead = lexan();
  start();
}

void start ()
{
  /* Just one production for start, so we don't need to check lookahead */
  list(); match(DONE);
}

void list()
{
  if (lookahead == '(' || lookahead == ID || lookahead == NUM) {
    expr(); match(';'); list();
  }
  else {
    /* Empty */
  }
}

void expr ()
{
  /* Just one production for expr, so we don't need to check lookahead */
  term(); moreterms();
}

void moreterms()
{
  if (lookahead == '+') {
    match('+'); term(); emit('+', tokenval); moreterms();
  }
  else if (lookahead == '-') {
    match('-'); term(); emit('-', tokenval); moreterms();
  }
  else {
    /* Empty */
  }
}

void term ()
{
  /* Just one production for term, so we don't need to check lookahead */
  factor(); morefactors();
}

void morefactors ()
{
  if (lookahead == '*') {
    match('*'); factor(); emit('*', tokenval); morefactors();
  }
  else if (lookahead == '/') {
    match('/'); factor(); emit('/', tokenval); morefactors();
  }
  else if (lookahead == DIV) {
    match(DIV); factor(); emit(DIV, tokenval); morefactors();
  }
  else if (lookahead == MOD) {
    match(MOD); factor(); emit(MOD, tokenval); morefactors();
  }
  else {
    /* Empty */
  }
}

void factor ()
{
  if (lookahead == '(') {
    match('('); expr(); match(')');
  }
  else if (lookahead == ID) {
    int id_lexeme = tokenval;
    match(ID);
    emit(ID, id_lexeme);
  }
  else if (lookahead == NUM) {
    int num_value = tokenval;
    match(NUM);
    emit(NUM, num_value);
  }
  else
    error("syntax error in factor");
}

void match(int t)
{
  if (lookahead == t)
    lookahead = lexan();
  else
    error ("syntax error in match");
}
/* error.c */

void error(char* m)  /* generates all error messages  */
{
  fprintf(stderr, "line %d: %s\n", lineno, m);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  /*  unsuccessful termination  */
}
/* main.c */

int main(void)
{
  init();
  parse();
  exit(0);    /*  successful termination  */
}



/*BOLD*/ int lexan()  /*  lexical analyzer  */
{

  int t;
  while(1) {
    t = getchar ();
    if (t == ' ' || t == '\t')
      ;  /*  strip out white space  */
    else if (t == '\n')
      lineno = lineno + 1;
    else if (isdigit (t)) {  /*  t is a digit  */
      ungetc(t, stdin);
      scanf("%d", &tokenval);
      return NUM;
    }
    else if (isalpha(t)) {  /*  t is a letter */
      int p, b = 0;
      while (isalnum(t)) {  /* t is alphanumeric  */
        lexbuf [b] = t; 
        t = getchar ();
        b = b + 1;
        if (b >= BSIZE)
          error("compiler error");
      }
      lexbuf[b] = EOS;
      if (t != EOF)
        ungetc(t, stdin);
      p = lookup (lexbuf);
      if (p == 0)
        p = insert (lexbuf, ID);
      tokenval = p;
      return symtable[p].token;
    }
    else if (t == EOF)
      return DONE;
    else {
      tokenval = NONE;
      return t;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#, VB or Matlab?

Comment: This looks like C, not C++, C#, vb.net, matlab or vb.  Also, what is your error?  Is it not compiling?  Is it returning wrong values?  Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a whole bunch of compiler errors:

```
$ cc -c a.c
a.c:18: warning: ‘tokenval’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
a.c:19: warning: ‘lineno’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
a.c:31: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘extern’
a.c:267: error: redefinition of ‘lexan’
a.c:90: note: previous definition of ‘lexan’ was here
```

If you'd read the line numbers, you could have solved these yourself.

One by one:

```
extern int tokenval = NONE;
extern int lineno = 1;
```

assigns in an `extern` declaration. That's not allowed. Remove `extern`. In fact, you don't need any of the `extern` modifiers, since all the code is in the current module.

```
int lexan();  /*  lexical analyzer  */**
                 // the error is here ^^
```

The last error is that `lexan` is defined twice.